# Android Databinding onClick() not getting registered on a simple View

Tags: android, android-databinding

I am trying to call a method from my ViewModel through data binding, but the method isn't called. This is how the view looks:

```
<View
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:alpha="0.8"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:onClick="@{()->viewmodel.onViewClicked())}"
/>
```

If I change the view to a button instead, without modifying anything else, it works as it is, so I think this may be a weird interraction between simple View and databinding. I also tried adding clickable:"true", it still doesn't work.

Do you guys have any idea why this may happen ?

Comment: Did you remember to use `setViewModel()` on the generated binding class?

Comment: Yes I did. I told you, it works if I just change View to Button, with everything else the same. So the viewmodel is set. Somehow the click is not getting registered I think

Comment: You can debug into the generated code and see what is going on. There is no difference to data binding whether it is a button or View and android shouldn't care either. I've used view onClick many times with data binding without any problems, so I know it isn't a fundamental issue. It should simply be calling `setOnClickListener()`. Is there a chance that you're calling `setOnClickListener()` from somewhere else, overriding the listener set here?

Comment: If i was calling setOnClickListener() from anywhere else, shouldn't the button also be affected ?

Comment: I don't know what your other code looks like. You could easily have `if (view instanceof Button)`. You could also have a BindingAdapter that takes a Button as a parameter. Look in the generated Binding for some clue as to what is happening. It should be calling either `ViewBindingAdapter.setClickListener()` or `View.setOnClick()`. If either of those is being called, look at the class of the listener. I think you should be able to attach a breakpoint to it and see what it is doing when the click happens.

Comment: Apparently, the issue is the parent Constraint Layout. Another View comes above my view, and the click is not registered. If I make it button, the button goes above everything else and then it is registered, really weird stuff.